# Macbook pro can connect to wifi but not internet, needs restart Macbook

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, internet

I recently get a new MacBook Pro 16-inch, 2023 with macOS 13.4.1 and have encountered an issue with its internet connectivity. While at the office or home, the laptop connects to the WiFi without any problems. However, when I leave the office and return home, I face difficulties in connecting to the internet. The status bar indicates a successful WiFi connection, but I am unable to access websites like Google.

To resolve this issue, I have found that restarting the MacBook is necessary in order to restore internet functionality.

Comment: Try flushing your DNS cache:  `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

Comment: Try setting new Locations for work & home; that might allow you to just switch between them without a reboot.